# Prevent electron from opening multiple app instances

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using the approach below according to official electron docs:

```
export const onAppTryLaunch = () => {
  const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

  // if another app instance is already running
  if (!gotTheLock) {
        app.quit();
  } else {
    // main instance event
    app.on('second-instance', () => {
      openMainWindow(); // my function to focus/restore app window
    });
  }
};
```

But it leads to a problem - the **new app process appears anyway** and stays in the system's process list as a ghost.

To be precise: on the second launch electron starts several new app processes and all except one are close for sure, but one of them always stays as a ghost, consuming the system's resources, and won't be closed on the main process exit.

Does anyone know a way to avoid this broken piece of code?

In similar questions, I found only the way I used already in this one and the old API(unable to use in the current version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution by calling `onAppTryLaunch()` (the function with the electron API to prevent new instance launch) **before any other code**.

Yes, the `app.quite()` should close the app anyway, but sometimes it doesn't(you think it did, but the new ghost process of the app has started and won't be closed if the main app has been shut down), and even `app.exit()` won't help, so make sure to close your app before calling any other stuff, even before the app is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it, I don't seem to have the ghost problem that you have.

```js
app.on("second-instance", () => {
  if (!mainWindow) return;

  if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
  mainWindow.focus();
});
```